# shebang for custom shell?

Tags: linux, shell

I'm writing a custom shell and I want it to execute a script:

```
if [ type less > /dev/null ];then PAGER=less; fi
echo $PAGER
printenv|grep $1|$PAGER
```

It works if I run it from the bash and with my custom shell:

```
$ ./shell -f ../checkenv.sh GNOME
[13607] 
[13606] 
GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL=
GNOME_KEYRING_PID=
GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID=this-is-deprecated
INSTANCE=GNOME
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=GNOME
(END)
```

But if I start my shell and then try and run the script, I get an error message.

```
$ ./shell 
'PATH' is set to /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/local/go/bin.
$ ../checkenv.sh GNOME
14786: executing ../checkenv.sh
../checkenv.sh: 2: [: type: unexpected operator

14786: executed
$
```

This seems to be because I don't have a shebang, but I don't know how to use a shebang for a custom shell. Should I install my custom shell in `/usr/bin/` or make some other arrangement?

My main function and my readline function are:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    bool donotrun = false;
    struct sigaction new_action, old_action;
    hashtable_t *hashtable = ht_create(65536);
    /* Set up the structure to specify the new action. */
    new_action.sa_handler = termination_handler;
    sigemptyset(&new_action.sa_mask);
    new_action.sa_flags = 0;

    sigaction(SIGINT, NULL, &old_action);
    if (old_action.sa_handler != SIG_IGN)
        sigaction(SIGINT, &new_action, NULL);
    sigaction(SIGHUP, NULL, &old_action);
    if (old_action.sa_handler != SIG_IGN)
        sigaction(SIGHUP, &new_action, NULL);
    sigaction(SIGTERM, NULL, &old_action);
    if (old_action.sa_handler != SIG_IGN)
        sigaction(SIGTERM, &new_action, NULL);

    bool background = false;
    int index = 0;
    int i;
    char *cvalue = NULL;
    const char *commandFile = NULL;

    while (1) {
        index = 0;
        i = getopt_long(argc, argv, "pc:fvh",
                        options, &index);
        if (i == -1)
            break;
        switch (i) {
            case 'p': {
                exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
            }
            case 'v': {
                printf("sh OpenShell version 0.1(a)\n");
                printf("Version: %s\n", VERSION);

              //  printf ("%s / %s / %s / %s\n",
                //         program_name, version,
                  //       build_date, build_git_sha);


                exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

            }
            case 'h': {
                usage();
                exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

            }
            case 'c': {
                cvalue = optarg;
                command(cvalue, hashtable, background);
                exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
            }

            case 'f': {
                /*
                 * Execute commands from file.
                 * This is used for osh script files.
                 * The quiet flag is also set.
                 */
                //if ((argc != 1) || commandFile)
                    //usage();
                //quietFlag = TRUE;
                printf("case f\n");
                //commandFile = *argv++;

                argc--;
                *argv++;
                *argv++;
                readFile(*argv++, argc, argv, hashtable, background);
                //free(line);
                exit(0);

                //break;
            }

            case '?':
                if (optopt == 'c')
                    fprintf(stderr, "Option -%c requires an argument.\n", optopt);
                else if (isprint (optopt))
                    fprintf(stderr, "Unknown option `-%c'.\n", optopt);
                else
                    fprintf(stderr,
                            "Unknown option character `\\x%x'.\n",
                            optopt);
            default: {
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }
    getPath();
    char *copy = "";

    for (; ;) {
        bool scanning = true;
        while (scanning) {
            char *line = NULL;
            line = readline("$ ");
            if (line == NULL) {
                /* No more lines, so exit the loop. */
                break;
            }
            if (line)
                copy = strdup(line);

            if (line && !strstr(line, "for") && !strstr(line, "==") && !strstr(line, "if") && strstr(line, "=")) {
                donotrun = true;
                char str[128];
                char *ptr;
                strcpy(str, line);
                strtok_r (str, "=", &ptr);
                ht_set(hashtable, str, ptr);
            }

            if (!scanning)
                break;

            if (commandFile!=NULL || !isatty(fileno(stdin))) {
                *argv++;
                readFile(*argv++, argc, argv, hashtable, background);
                free(line);
                exit(0);
            }
            else {
                if (!donotrun) {
                    line = strrep(line, " | ", "|");
                    line = strrep(line, " |", "|");
                    background = testFn2(line);
                    if (background)
                        line[strlen(line) - 1] = '\0';
                    command(line, hashtable, background);
                }
                donotrun = false;
                add_history(copy);

            }
            free(copy);
        }
    }
    //  ParseFree(pParser, free);FIXME: where should this go?
    return 0;
}


/*
 * Read commands from the specified file.
 * A null name pointer indicates to read from stdin.
 */
static int readFile(const char *name, int argc, char ** argv, hashtable_t *hashtable, bool background) {
    FILE *fp;
    int cc;
    bool ttyFlag;
    char buf[CMD_LEN];
    int r = 0;

    if (sourceCount >= MAX_SOURCE) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Too many source files\n");

        return 1;
    }

    fp = stdin;
    printf("name %s\n", name);

    if (name) {
        fp = fopen(name, "r");

        if (fp == NULL) {
            perror(name);

            return 1;
        }
    }

    sourcefiles[sourceCount++] = fp;

    ttyFlag = isatty(fileno(fp));
    int i = 0;
    while (true) {
        if (ttyFlag)
            showPrompt();

        if (intFlag && !ttyFlag && (fp != stdin)) {
            fclose(fp);
            sourceCount--;

            return 1;
        }
        if (fgets(buf, CMD_LEN - 1, fp) == NULL) {
            if (ferror(fp) && (errno == EINTR)) {
                clearerr(fp);

                continue;
            }

            break;
        }

        cc = strlen(buf);
        if (buf[cc - 1] == '\n')
            cc--;

        while ((cc > 0) && isBlank(buf[cc - 1]))
            cc--;

        buf[cc] = '\0';
        //printf("buf %s\n", argv[0]);
        strreplace(buf, "$1", argv[0]);

        //printf("arg %s\n", ++argv);

        if (strstr(buf, "=")) {
            char str[128];
            char *ptr;
            strcpy(str, buf);
            strtok_r (str, "=", &ptr);
            ht_set(hashtable, str, ptr);
        }

        //printf("the command is %s\n", buf);
        r = command(buf, hashtable, background);
        i++;
    }

    if (ferror(fp)) {
        perror("Reading command line");

        if (fp == stdin)
            exit(1);
    }

    clearerr(fp);

    if (fp != stdin)
        fclose(fp);

    sourceCount--;

    return r;
}
```

Comment: It is not clear how this is related to C or the source code of your shell. She-bang is a feature of the execution environment and no way related to C.

Comment: Why not try `#!/path/to/my/shell` out and see what happens?

Comment: BTW, `[ ]` is not part of `if` syntax. It's not an equivalent or alternatives to parens or braces as grouping operators. Literally, `[` is an alias for the `test` command; `if [ 2 -gt 1 ]` is **in any every respect** equivalent to `if test 2 -gt 1` (every shell whose source I've read has them both implemented by the same function), and you'll see that your OS provides a `/usr/bin/[` just as it does a `/usr/bin/test` (though modern shells will have a builtin version of both that's faster to start, hence the builtin version described above).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might simply remove the square brackets in your script test:

```
if type less > /dev/null ;then PAGER=less; fi
echo $PAGER
printenv|grep $1|$PAGER
```

Answer (score 3):

A shebang line simply specifies the full path to the interpreter, plus (optionally) an argument to be passed.

Apparently your custom shell requires a `-f` followed by the script name, followed by any arguments to be passed to the script.

So just add this as the first line of your script:

```
#!/path/to/shell -f
```

and make sure the script has execute permissions.  Your shell doesn't have to be installed in `/usr/bin`; you just have to specify the full path on the `#!` line.

There's also a `/usr/bin/env` hack:

```
#!/usr/bin/env shell
```

but on many systems it doesn't permit passing an extra argument. (You *might* consider modifying your custom shell so it takes the script name as an argument without the `-f`.)  I've discussed the pros and cons of `#!/usr/bin/env` in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/29620/10454).

Note that the `#!` mechanism is handled by the kernel, not by the shell.